# Make calculation with related data table in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, model

I want to do tax calculations directly in the model.
I have 2 models for this:

1.) UST

```
public partial class Ust
{
    public Ust()
    {
        Buchungen = new HashSet<Buchungen>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public int Steuer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Buchungen> Buchungen { get; set; }
}
```

2.) Buchungen

```
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Netto
    {
        get
        {
            return Brutto - Ust;
        }
        set
        { }
    }
    public int UstId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Ust
    {
        get
        {
            return UstNavigation.Steuer * Brutto / 100;
        }
        set
        { }
    }
    public decimal? Brutto { get; set; }

    public virtual Ust UstNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

The data "Brutto" as well as the selection of the Ust via UstId are entered in a "Create" view.

Now I would like to calculate "Ust" and "Netto" for bookings.

"Netto" is already working. (If i manually deposit an amount for Ust)

But I have my problem with the "Ust" amount.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I imagined it.

I tried something like.

```
get
  if (UstNavigation.Steuer != null)
    {
      return UstNavigation.Steuer * Brutto / 100;
    }
set
   { }
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea whether this is even possible?

Comment: "doesn't work either" What do you mean? You have to post a presize error if you want to get some help.

Comment: @Serge
When i use "return UstNavigation.Steuer" I got the following error.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix the exception , but  I am not sure if your can get any data

```
get
{
  if ( UstNavigation != null && UstNavigation.Steuer != null)
  return UstNavigation.Steuer * Brutto / 100;
 
  return null;

  //or in one line
  return UstNavigation != null && UstNavigation.Steuer != null ? UstNavigation.Steuer * Brutto / 100 : null

}
```

it will work only if UstId>0 and you  use Include UstNavigation  in your EF query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that works.
If anyone cares -- my calculation was wrong.

Now it works with:

`return UstNavigation != null ? Brutto - (Brutto * 100 / (100 + UstNavigation.Steuer))`